# Need to access Dropbox files within Phonegap app supporting Windows 8 and Android

Tags: android, cordova, windows-8, dropbox-api

I am having difficulty in finding a solution for this issue.

I have an existing web application using JS, HTML and CSS with which I have used Phonegap to support both Android and Windows 8.

What I need now is a back-end to access Dropbox files - but I am confused in what I need to get going as it seems supporting both Android and Windows simultaneously is difficult / impossible.

I have also looked at using OneDrive to access files, but I have run into the same problem.

Is it possible to use the Dropbox / OneDrive API to access files in a Phonegap app supporting multiple platforms? If so, what do I need to get started?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Dropbox JS SDK for this. I recently wrote a blog post about it on the Dropbox developer blog: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/95/using-dropbox-datastores-in-a-cordova-app.

That post is specifically about using the Datastore API, but the same library supports files too.

Comment: Many thanks @smarx, I will look in to this tomorrow - hopefully it works! Will definitely report back on progress! I was not looking forward to the confusion of separate Windows and Android coding within a Phonegap application...So with that SDK you can read (that is, get) file information, i.e. of documents and images as well?

Comment: Yup! And the same JavaScript code should work on Android, iPhone, and Windows (8 and Phone).

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on using OneDrive for this? Or would you rather use Dropbox??

Comment: I work at Dropbox, so I might be too biased to answer that question. :-) That said, as long as OneDrive has a JavaScript SDK, you should be able to do the same thing with their product.

Comment: Hi @smarx, for syncing, do I need to use the separate Sync API? Or will the Datastore API be sufficient? Will the Sync API work with JS? Thanks!

Comment: The Sync API is one style of API for working with files. (It's really more of an SDK than an API.) There are only Sync SDKs for iOS and Android. The JS SDK does support working with files in addition to datastores, but it uses the Core API.

Comment: Many many thanks @smarx! Ok, hopefully last question...the android app of the example works perfectly on the tablet, but when I run the Cordova app for windows8 (on a Windows8 laptop) it gives a `JavaScript Runtime Error: Dropbox is undefined` but Dropbox is installed...do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: Ok, so it seems that Windows8 apps don't really like the CDN way of referencing a js library...so when I added jquery and the datastores js files, it worked. Well, until I ran into the problem with the example after clicking on "Link to Dropbox" - an error is displayed `The app couldn't navigate to ... because of this error: FORBIDFRAMING` do you perhaps know how to fix this?

Comment: This seems like an unrelated question, but I see that you did ask it as a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274286/dropbox-javascript-datastores-api-example-in-phonegap-provides-error-forbidframi.