# Dropbox Javascript Datastores API example in Phonegap provides error forbidframing for Windows8 app

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-8, dropbox-api

I have attempted to create a Phonegap app supporting both Android and Windows8 for the Dropbox Javascript Datastores API that makes use of the example provided here: https://github.com/dropbox/cordova-datastores-example

When I build and run the Android app, it runs perfectly on the Android tablet. But when I run the app created for Windows8, an error is displayed: `The app couldn't navigate to ... because of this error: FORBIDFRAMING`. And then nothing happens afterwards.

I haven't been able to find an alternative to using a frame. I would like to know, if there is a way to run the Windows8 app successfully of this example, and where I would change the example to replace the frame. (Or, if there is another way to auth a user sign in so that I don't have to use the frame.)

Thanks.

Comment: I'm just tackling the same issue. I'm currently trying out dropbox-js with the cordova authdriver. But that does not seem to work.

Comment: Hi @sdepold, do you have any alternative that you are looking at?

Comment: I'm just making some small steps into the right direction. Once I get it working, I will post a solution here.

Comment: Just found this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301831.aspx It seems that there actually is an alternative for iframes :)

Answer (score 3):

## Premise

This is a hacky solution which will probably be ported to a proper Pull Request against dropbox-js:

## Preparation:

- Download the dropbox-js client from [here](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropbox.js/0.10.2/dropbox.js) and put it into project's `js` folder.
- Ensure that it is listed in your "Solution Explorer". If it isn't, right click on the folder and add it via "Add -> Existing Item...".
- Add `dropbox.js` to your `default.html`.
- Create a new file. I called it `helpers.js` and add it to your `default.html`.
- Open your `package.appxmanifest` file and declare a custom protocol. (Declarations -> Select protocol from the drop down -> Give it a name (e.g. myapp))
- Go to the dropbox [app console](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps) and register a new application.
- Add a Redirect URI to the registered app: `myapp://dropbox`. Note that `myapp` references the custom protocol.

## Step #1: Add helpers

Add the following content to the `helpers.js`:
http://pastebin.com/qpZbv7YG

## Step #2: Add support for the protocol handler

As we added the custom protocol to our app and the redirect uri to dropbox, we need to handle
the call from dropbox.  your `default.js`

```
app.addEventListener("activated", function (args) {
  if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.protocol) {
    // the application has been called via the custom protocol

    var requestUri = args.detail.uri.rawUri
      , params     = Dropbox.Util.Oauth.queryParamsFromUrl(requestUri)

    AppHelpers.dropbox.setParams(params)
  } else if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
    /* you should have this alread in place */
  }
})
```

## Step #3: Add a custom AuthDriver to dropbox-js

Open dropbox.js and find the line:

```
  Dropbox.AuthDriver.Cordova = (function (_super) {
```

Paste the following code just above that line:

```
Dropbox.AuthDriver.WinRT = (function (_super) {
  __extends(WinRT, _super);

  function WinRT(options) {
    WinRT.__super__.constructor.call(this, options);
  }

  WinRT.prototype.url = function () {
    return 'myapp://dropbox';
  };

  WinRT.prototype.doAuthorize = function (authUrl, stateParam, client, callback) {
    var authHost, browser, onEvent, promptPageLoaded, removed,
      _this = this;
    var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(authUrl);

    Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(uri)
  };

  return WinRT;
})(Dropbox.AuthDriver.BrowserBase);
```

Please note that there is again a reference to our custom protocol.

## Step #4: Use dropbox

In the helpers.js you will find a function called `sync` which I use to

- check if the user is already authenticated. If that is not yet the case, we will redirect him to dropbox.
- download the user's contact data and log it into the console.

You basically just have to use `MyHelpers.dropbox.getClient()` and interact with the resulting client. It will return a proper instance of the [dropbox client](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/stable/guides/getting_started.md)

## Final words

Hope that helps!
You can find available methods of the client here: http://coffeedoc.info/github/dropbox/dropbox-js/master/classes/Dropbox/Client.html#readFile-instance

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md, it looks like Windows isn't actually supported by the InAppBrowser plugin (which is what is used by the Dropbox Cordova auth driver).

Comment: Thanks @smarx, so does that mean I would not be able to use Dropbox for the Windows side?

Comment: You certainly could without Cordova (i.e. without using a frame). With Cordova, I'm not entirely sure. You might have to write your own code to handle the Dropbox authentication part.

Comment: hello @smarx can you please tell me, can we choose image or file from dropbox folder in android phone using dropbox cordova plugin ? i am able to choose the files that are not in folder but the files in folder are not choosing.